# Mockito Matching parameterized method with multiple interface

Tags: mockito, matcher

Hi I've created a nice interface for my service which accepts object implementing 2 interfaces, but now I have difficulties to create a matcher for this interface.

Anyone has any idea how to create a matcher for the following?

```
<T extends HasDocumentTags & HasResources> ResponseEntity<Void> setDocumentMetadata(T t);
```

Just an any() wouldn't help here, as the method is overloaded already twice

```
ResponseEntity<Void> setDocumentMetadata(List<Document> attachments);
ResponseEntity<Void> setDocumentMetadata(ApproveDocumentsCommand<?> command);
```

Now I'm trying to mock the service and defining an answer

```
when(service.setDocumentMetadata( ??? ).thenReturn(anAnswer);
```

I just can't figure out the right matcher for any(), eq() or whatever will be working.
Or am I trying thing which aren't possible (in java8)?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use any for type Document and ApproveDocumentsCommand:

```
when(service.setDocumentMetadata(any(Document.class)).thenReturn(anAnswer1);
when(service.setDocumentMetadata(any(ApproveDocumentsCommand.class)).thenReturn(anAnswer2);
```

I this any(Document.class) and any(ApproveDocumentsCommand.class) should be enoght.

also you can use ArgumentMatcher , if you need check type for arguments with some extra checks:

```
    when(service.setDocumentMetadata(argThat(new MyCommonMatcher<>())))
         .thenReturn(responseEntityOk);
    when(service.setDocumentMetadata(argThat(new MyDocumentMatcher<>())))
        .thenReturn(responseEntityOk);
    when(service.setDocumentMetadata(argThat(new MyApproveDocumentsCommandMatcher<>()))) 
       .thenReturn(responseEntityOk);

class MyCommonMatcher<T extends HasDocumentTags & HasResources> 
                                                      extends ArgumentMatcher<T>{

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        return (argument instanceof HasResources) && (argument instanceof HasDocumentTags);
    }
}

class MyDocumentMatcher<T extends HasDocumentTags & HasResources> 
                                                       extends ArgumentMatcher<T>{

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        return argument instanceof Document;
    }
}

class MyApproveDocumentsCommandMatcher<T extends HasDocumentTags & HasResources> 
                                                         extends ArgumentMatcher<T>{

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        return argument instanceof ApproveDocumentsCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer!